# boost msm class?

Tags: class, boost, state-machine

I am newbi to boost msm and boost in general.
I would like to somehow encapsulate all the:

- event structures
- stateMahine structure containing the transition table structure and the state structures

within a Class.

How can I do that?

```
// events
struct event1 {};



// front-end: define the FSM structure 
struct my_machine_ : public msm::front::state_machine_def<my_machine_>
{
    // The list of FSM states
    struct State1 : public msm::front::state<> 
    {
        // every (optional) entry/exit methods get the event passed.
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_entry(Event const&,FSM& ) {std::cout << "entering: State1" << std::endl;}
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_exit(Event const&,FSM& ) {std::cout << "leaving: State1" << std::endl;}
    };

    struct State2 : public msm::front::state<> 
    { 
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_entry(Event const& ,FSM&) {std::cout << "entering: State3" << std::endl;}
        template <class Event,class FSM>
        void on_exit(Event const&,FSM& ) {std::cout << "leaving: State3" << std::endl;}


    };

    // the initial state of the player SM. Must be defined
    typedef State1 initial_state;

    typedef my_machine_ p; // makes transition table cleaner

    // Transition table
    struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
        //    Start     Event         Next      Action               Guard
        //  +---------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
        Row < State1  , event1      , State2                                               >,
        Row < State2  , event1      , State1                                           >
    > {};

};
```

Comment: What do you mean by encapsulate?

Comment: I would like to put the above structures in a class, and have a header file that I can add to whomever that want to use the statemachine

Comment: I'm baffled. The above structure is already a class (struct) and I see nothing that prevents you from putting it into a header file.

Comment: I am trying to avoid implementing the on_entry/on_exit methods in the .h file

Comment: So you are essentially asking how you can implement the member of a nested struct in an implementation file?

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks for clarifying the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the member of a nested use:

```
// header file
struct Foo {
  struct Nested {
    void mem();
  };
};
// cpp file
void Foo::Nested::mem() {
  // implementation goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this question not long ago.
If you declare the nested Fsm structure in the header, you'll pay for higher compile-times wherever included.
An alternative would be:

```
// PublicClass.hpp
struct PublicClass
{
  // forward-declare nested type. This will inherit msm::back::state_machine<...>
  struct Fsm;
  // with shared_ptr, you don't need the complete type yet.
  boost::shared_ptr<Fsm> fsm_;
};

// PublicClass.cpp
// provide definition of Fsm.
struct PublicClass::Fsm : public msm::back::state_machine<my_machine_>{};
```

HTH,
Christophe

Comment: Just wondering, wouldn't this issue be resolved by using #ifndef #define arround the header file, so it can only be scanned once by compiler?

Comment: no because it wouldn't solve the problem of different translation units including this header. For each of them, you would need to pay the compile-time cost.